# How to inject HTML to page with Cordova's InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm running single page web app inside InAppBrowser. I want to inject HTML attributes into some HTML elements. For example change all h1 to h2.

I know I can use executeScript method for short tasks like this:

```
win.executeScript({ code: "console.log( 'hello' );" })
```

Does anybody know what is the best way to run longer script with executeScript method and how to make sure it runs after everything is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to inject a lot of code you should use a js file instead of using just a code string. To inject code from a .js file and making sure the page is loaded you have to run executescript when the loadstop event is called, something like this:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    ref.executeScript({file: "http://www.yourwebsite.com/myscript.js"});
});
```

`file` has to be an external js if you are loading an external website, but can be a local js if you are loading a local html file

Comment: Is it so that the file can't be local?

Comment: no, it has to be a remote file, it just creates a script tag and append it on the website body

Comment: In fact it depends.

If the opened in app browser window is loading an external html file, it has to be a remote file. However, if it's running a local file, you can also execute local scripts.

Comment: Didn't know that, will add it to the answer, thanks!